# CMV streetview widget a violation of Google API Terms of service?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, google-street-view

Information I just received from the state states the ESRI has to remove their street view widget from (I assume) ArcGIS online. This is the post on GEOnet: https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-2991?messageTarget=all&start=100&mode=comments

Should I remove it or be concerned?

Comment: I dont think you're going to get an authoritative yes/no answer on this here at gis.SE. To provide a good answer one would need to be in a position (legally speaking) to talk about google / esri terms of service. Anything else is simply opinion.

Comment: your are correct just wondered what the thoughts of the CMV users/creators were on the issue. First I heard about it. Has anyone here taken it off their site due to the ESRI decision? I read the TOS yesterday and it contradicts itself so I am unsure.